# Внесение изменений в конфигурационный с помощью Ansible

Tags: ansible

Добрый день. Хотел бы узнать, возможно ли с помощью ansible открывать конфигурационные файлы и изменять их содержимое (ip-адреса, порт и тд..), а так же какие модули для этого используются?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html

Answer (score 2):

Вечер добрый.

Как раз этим сейчас занимаюсь, перевожу кучу рабочих скриптов в один плейбук.

Интересующие вас модули

- [raw](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/raw_module.html)
- [temlate](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/template_module.html)
- [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/lineinfile_module.html)

Примеры

#### raw

Модуль позволяет выполнять команды на "сыром" уровне без прослойки Python,
пользуясь уже установленными программами в системе (sed, grep, egrep, awk).

```
---

tasks:
  - name: "изменить маску подсети"
    raw: sed -i -e 's/.*subnetmask.*/subnetmask 255.255.255.0/g' /etc/network/interfaces
```

#### template

Очень мощный модуль основанный на системе профилирования [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9). Можно,
например задать разметку файла /etc/network/interfaces, который будет
генерироваться динамически, в зависимости от указанного сервера.

- *host_vars*

host_number_one

```
tb_eth0_ipv4_address = 192.168.1.111
tb_eth0_ipv4_gateway = 255.255.255.128
tb_eth1_ipv4_address = 192.168.241.111
```

- *roles*

  - *role_name*

    - *templates*

interfaces.j2

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address {{ tb_eth0_ipv4_address | default(".".join(ansible_eth0.ipv4.address.split(".")[0:3])+".111") }}
gateway {{ tb_eth0_ipv4_gateway | default(".".join(ansible_eth0.ipv4.address.split(".")[0:3])+".111") }}
netmask 255.255.255.128
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# 2nd LAN range
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address {{ tb_eth1_ipv4_address | default("192.168.241.111") }}
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

- *roles*

  - *tasks*

main.yml

```
---

hosts: host_number_one

- name: "Профилирование конфигурационного файла /etc/network/interfaces"
  template:
    src: interfaces.j2
    dest: /etc/nework/interfaces
    owner: root
    group: root
```

#### lineinfile

Тоже полезный модуль, интересен тем, что может "включать-выключать" определенные
строки в конфиге (sudoers, vsftpd.con), с дополнительно проверкой на валидность.

```
---

hosts: all
  tasks:

    - name: "Изменение и проверка файла /etc/sudoers"
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/sudoers
        state: present
        regexp: '^%ADMIN ALL='
        line: '%ADMIN ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
        validate: '/usr/sbin/visudo -cf %s'
```